# Difference between Süd and Süden

Tags: meaning, noun

What exactly is the difference between Süd and Süden, and when should one or other be used?

Which is correct: "Ich komme aus dem Süd" or "Ich komme aus dem Süden"?

And how exactly would you translate "Wir sind Süden"?  "We are the South" or maybe "We are Southern/Southerners"?

Comment: Side note: _der Süd_ can be the name of a wind blowing from the south. And _die Süd_ is colloquial for a highway in Austria (_die Südautobahn_). But both of these are shortenings of words with _Süd_ as a prefix (_Südwind_, _Südautobahn_).

Comment: For last paragraph, the statement you want to make is a better basis for an answer than a misunderstandable translation attempt (which in this case happens to be wrong).

Answer (score 4):

Wrong:

> Ich komme aus dem Süd
>   Wir sind Süd
>   Wir sind Süden

To translate these word clusters that aren't correct sentences doesn't make any sense.

Correct:

> 1. Ich komme aus dem Süden
> 2. Wir sind im Süden

The translations of the correct sentences are:

> 1. I'm coming from the south. (verbatim: ... out of the south)
> 2. We are in the south.

Süd most often appears only as a prefix. (Südpol = south pole, Südfrucht = tropical fruit.) It appears as real single word only in names

- Shopping Center Süd
  Name of the largest shopping center in Austria, south of Vienna (outside of Vienna)
- Bildungszentrum Graz Süd
  Name of an education center in the south of Graz (inside of Graz)
- Aldi Süd
  Name of a food store chain that has stores in southern parts of Germany

In all other cases it is "Süden".

Comment: Na ja, "Wir sind der Süden." könnte auch noch korrekt sein.

Comment: "Ich bin Nord, wo seids ihr?" "Wir sind Süd" -- that's surely possible in the "Ich bin Kino" Sociolect :) (Not to say that I endorse that...)

Comment: @Hubert, an dieser Stelle eine Frage: ich kenne "wir fahren in den Norden". Kann man hier auch die Präposition "nach" ("nach Norden") benutzen?

Comment: @Serena: Ja. "in den ..." bedeutet eigentlich, dass das Ziel ein Ort ist ("in den Wald", "in den Palast", "in den Kosovo"). "nach ..." bedeutet eine Richtung ("nach unten", "nach links", "nach vorne"). "Norden" ist eigentlich kein Ort, sondern eine Richtung, daher ist "nach Norden" für gewöhnlich sogar besser "in den Norden".

Comment: @Hubert, vielen Dank! Ich kann nicht aufhören zu staunen - im Sprachkurs wurde uns immer beigebracht, dass die Präp. "nach" NUR mit Städten/Ländern + in Kombinationen "nach links/nach rechts" verwendet wird...

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use "Süd", "Süden" or "südlich" depends on the context of what you are trying to say.

First, to directly answer your question:

> Which is correct: "Ich komme aus dem Süd" or "Ich komme aus dem Süden"?

"Ich komme aus dem Süden" would be right.

> And how exactly would you translate "Wir sind Süden"? "We are the South" or maybe "We are Southern/Southerners"?

This depends on the context. "Wir sind Süden" probably wouldn't be said in normal speech. If someone were to say "We are the South", they would probably say "Wir sind *der* Süden".

If they said "We are Southerners" there is even one more destinction:

If they were trying to say that they are from the south of germany, they would probably say "Wir sind Süddeutsche". Which uses the prefix "Süd" and combines it with "german". So basically, "We are south-germans".

If they are trying to say that they are from a southern country (e.g. Italy and Greece are considered "southern" in europe), then they would say "Wir sind Südländer", which means "We are south-landers".

Ill try to explain the basic rules behind this, although Ill have to say, take this with a grain of salt, as Im not 100% sure about the accuracy and the perfect grammatical reasoning. Just from the perspective of a native speaker:

Saying things like "Wir sind Süden" sounds a lot like a slogan. It feels like they try to say "We are the essence/heart of the south" or "We represent the south" or "This is what the south is like". The reason for that is, that one would usually use an article in that sentence. "Wir sind *der* Süden". This feels more like they are identifying with a specific, southern area. 
Its like a company saying "We are best" instead of "We are *the* best".

"Süd" is usually not used alone. Nobody really says "Ich fahr süd". Cant say if that would 100% be wrong, but nobody says it like that. One either says "Ich fahre in den Süden" or "Ich fahre südlich". Here, the first one is usually used to say that your destination is some southern location. Like Bavaria in Germany for example. Whereas "Ich fahre südlich" is usually used if you are trying to describe your path, when "the south" is not necessarily your destination. Its basically saying "Im takint the southern road" or something like that. "Süd" itself is only ever used as a prefix or suffix.

- "Süddeutschland" = Southern Germany
- "ALDI-Süd" = The southern branch of the "ALDI"-company.
- "Süd-Stuttgart" or "Stuttgart-Süd" = The southern part of the city "Stuttgart"

I cant really tell if there is a "rule" to whether it has to be used as a pre- or suffix. As far as I can tell, thats pretty arbitrary and basically depends on what sounds better. In the examples given, it seems like locations or areas can use it with either prefix or suffix, like Stuttgart, and it wouldnt sound odd.
For "Names", like the name of the company "ALDI", it would sound odd to say "Süd-ALDI". Here only the suffix works.

Answer (score 0):

Wir sind Süden ist nonsense. It means we are the south. If you want to say "we are southerners" it would be "wir kommen aus dem Süden".

Süden means South. Süd is a prefix for other locations like Südbahnhof or Süddeutschland.

Comment: "Wir sind Süden" ist der [offizielle Tourismus-Slogan Baden-Württembergs](https://www.stuttgarter-zeitung.de/inhalt.neuer-slogan-wir-sind-sueden.3b0524c9-661e-40af-bf3e-cc6609a68d3f.html). Spätestens seit "Wir sind Papst" sind solche Konstrukte (je nach Kontext) verständlich und "geflügelter" Teil der Sprache.

Comment: Verständlich? Ansichtssache. Unsinn ist es trotzdem.

Comment: Genau. Sie können alles. Außer Hochdeutsch.

Comment: @mtwde: Ich kenne den Werbespruch nicht. Ein Werbespruch existiert für sich selbst, evtl. noch als Verballhornung, aber als grammatische Regel gelangt er nicht in die Sprache. Für jeden, der den Werbespruch nicht kennt und der gerade damit, sprachlich falsch zu sein, Aufmerksamkeit erregen will, klingt er weiterhin falsch. Für jeden, der ihn kennt, wirkt es, als würde sich ein Verwender auf diesen Spruch beziehen. Fremdsprachlern würde ich solchen Unfug nicht beibringen, allenfalls erklären, wenn sie darüber stolpern. Ich bin 2 Öltanks. Be Berlin. Unkaputtbar.

Comment: @userunknown ich kannte den Werbespruch auch nicht. Allerdings ist erkennbar, dass dieser analog zur sehr bekannten Bild-Schlagzeile von 2005 "[Wir sind Papst](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wir_sind_Papst!)" gebildet wurde, die vielfältig auch schon auf andere Weise kopiert wurde. Dass der Satz nicht den Regeln entspricht ist klar; dass man ihn Fremdsprachlern nicht beibringen sollte auch. Ich würde ihn als gefügeltes Wort und "Spezialfall" einordnen, ähnlich wie Konstrukte a la "bächtig möse"